# Need a command to determine web site session timeout value

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

Is there a command I can run to see a web site's session timeout value.
I am setting the timeout in the sessionState block in my web.config but it looks like that value is being overridden by some other global IIS level setting.

Is there a way to see a web site's effective session timeout setting?
I would like to control session timeout in the web.config so I can override it but it doesn't seem to be working.

Thanks,

Brett

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in a test page use:

```
Response.Write(Session.Timeout.ToString());
```